# Getting the executable name of a QProcess in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, process, qprocess

Is there any possibility to figure out the executable name/path of a QProcess object? By now I only know that there is QProcess::pid() for identifying a process. Scouring the Qt doc hasn't lead to a useful solution so far.

Thanks in advance!

Example

```
int main() {
    QProcess* p = new QProcess(this);

    p->start("C:\\test.exe");

    func(p);

    return 0;
}

void func (QProcess* p)
{
     qDebug() << "The application name of the app with pid" << p->pid() << "is" << p->name(); // name() doesn't exist, that's where I need help
}
```

Comment: The code in your main function is not valid. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it on my mobile phone whilst sitting on the train. Should be better now.

Comment: It has already been suggested that you use `p.program()`. What output do you get from that, and how does it differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: I checked it in my application and it worked. The Qt doc explanation was just some misleading for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `program()` method of the QProcess object, like this:

```
QProcess process(this);
process.start("calc.exe");
qDebug() << process.program();
process.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: The Qt doc says "Returns the program the process was last started with" which is not what I want to have - I want to get the QProcess object's executable name or path, not the main one's.

Comment: Please add a sample how you used QProcess and what you expected to get

Comment: I added an example now.

Comment: What version of Qt you used? QProcess object hasn't a constructor with string argument and your code was not compiled with Qt5.